# How to fix image height and width in webview for android

Tags: android, image, size, webview

I am developing image application,i am using `WebView` to display image, so I want to fix some height and width size for the image, this size applicable for all kind of size of images in WebView.
Any sample code is welcome,

Thanks All

Answer (score 1):

If you are adding your image as an img src, here is the classical synthax :

```
<img src="yourimage.png" width=480 height=800 alt="your image"/>
```

Comment: @Thanks Sephy,i am not using img src,i am directly using img url in web view,i want fix some size for image and sit on web view...

Comment: What do you mean by "using url"? Do you download the image as an input stream for instance and display it or you simply connect to an url which points to an image on a server?

Comment: @i am displaying image using xml parsing and webview,so i said url, ok